# Нет msvcirtd.lib

Tags: библиотеки, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

У меня в MS Vis. 10 в папку lib нет вышеуказанного файла (msvcirtd.lib). Подкиньте кто-то, а то не компилирует (пишет Fatal error и т.д.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSVCRTD.DLL является отладочной версией стандартного файла Windows (MSVCRT.DLL), который отсутствует, если не установлена Visual C++ 6. Поэтому просто уставновите Visual C++ 6.0 и все заработает.

Comment: @userx MSVCRTD.DLL != msvcirtd.lib

Comment: @ReinRaus Точно, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

В топике [на MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/86ebc3ef-7bd8-432c-8e19-57013441d49d) дают два совета:

1. Вместо # include <iostream.h> пишите в коде # include <iostream>
2. Поискать во всех файлах проекта строку #pragma comment (lib, "msvcirtd.lib") и удалите ее.